# Add a where condition in one subquery referencing a table in another subquery (ANSI SQL)

Tags: sql

In subquery 'two' I want to add a where condition which is based on a column in subquery 'one', that is, I want to add  `WHERE   one."Call Type"  = 'Demo'` within my second subquery but that gives me an alias error. Basically, in 'two' I only want the count of those rows which have had a call type = demo as given in table 'one' (Final objective is to find the ratio of the two counts mentioned in the code). Any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

```
SELECT
         COALESCE(one.Period, two.Period) AS Period,
         one.TotalDemos,
         two.TotalTrials,
         Round(100.0 * one.TotalDemos / two.TotalTrials, 2) AS percentage
FROM (  SELECT
             "Call Date" AS Period,
             COUNT(*) AS TotalDemos
    FROM  "customer_calls" 
    WHERE    "Call Type"  = 'Demo'
    GROUP BY  Period 
) AS  one
FULL OUTER JOIN(    SELECT
             "modified" AS Period,
             COUNT(*) AS TotalTrials
    FROM  "users" 
    WHERE    "customertype"  = 0
    GROUP BY  Period 
) AS  two ON one.Period  = two.Period
```

Edit - My period values are as datestamps (date - time) whereas I'd want the aggregation or ratio/percentage by month of year instead of day. Not sure how that can be done using coalesce here. Any help on this would also be great.

Comment: you should join user and customer in 'two' subquery

Comment: Do `GROUP BY "modified"` in second subquery. ANSI SQL does not accept column aliases in the GROUP BY clause. (First subquery has the same problem.)

Comment: `period` is an ANSI SQL reserved word (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words), it needs to be delimited as `"period"`.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the table definitions that you've provided, you can achieve what you're after with [Common Table Expressions (CTE)](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-common-table-expressions-cte/). Example provided with the query below.

However, wee warning, trying to determine users that have made a demo call by just the `Period` is not recommended. If my assumption that `Period` is a date / time duration, then it is very likely that your query will not achieve what you want it to (i.e. you'll have records from the query that will not be a demo call). To get the query precise, you'll have to determine what the actual table joins between `customer_calls` and `users` are for your query to be effective.

Also, another wee warning, I generally don't recommend using `FULL OUTER JOIN` as it will return every record from both tables, meaning that you'll have a lot of records there that you don't want (i.e. lines in `one` that don't join to `two` and vice versa). `INNER JOIN` should suffice assuming you know the database / table structures well.

```
;WITH [one] AS (
    SELECT
         "Call Date" AS Period,
         COUNT(*) AS TotalDemos
    FROM  "customer_calls" 
    WHERE    "Call Type"  = 'Demo'
    GROUP BY  Period
), [two] AS (
    SELECT
         "modified" AS Period,
         COUNT(*) AS TotalTrials
    FROM  "users" 
    WHERE    "customertype"  = 0
        AND Period IN (SELECT Period FROM [one])
    GROUP BY  Period
)
SELECT
         COALESCE(one.Period, two.Period) AS Period,
         one.TotalDemos,
         two.TotalTrials,
         Round(100.0 * one.TotalDemos / two.TotalTrials, 2) AS percentage
FROM one
FULL OUTER JOIN two 
    ON one.Period = two.period
```

Comment: Note that square brackets around an identifier is not "standard SQL" (and standard SQL also needs the `;` at the end of the statement, not the beginning)

Comment: Apologies, they're both common habits when working with SQL Server (square brackets vs quote marks, semi-colon before WITH) - Though semi-colons usually come at the end of SQL queries, it is mainly to pre-empt common errors faced by SQL-related questions posted on S.O. - See thread (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23371/why-should-a-cte-start-with-a-semi-colon)

Comment: @MTay Thanks for this. I'll test it out soon. One thing I've now noticed is that since my timestamp is day wise, I'll be getting the ratio daywise whereas I'd want the aggregation by month of year instead. Not sure how this can be achieved with coalesce. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Quick answer: Assuming you are working with SQL Server, you can use the FORMAT() function - i.e. COALESCE(FORMAT(one.Period, 'MMM yyyy'), FORMAT(two.Period, 'MMM yyyy')). << This differs depending on which DB you're working with. Side note, coalesce returns the first non-null value in a list, which is probably right to use together with FULL OUTER JOINs (as you will be expecting NULLs in the list), but probably good to be aware that this has the potential to return a different result each time you run this query. Also, the query can be made less expensive, but that's another issue.

Comment: @MTay Also, I'm unclear on how we've considered the condition in 'two' where we only take 'users' from 'two' who've had demo calls. To be clear, both the tables have a userid column which is common and a timestamp column in each. What I want to achieve is the percentage of users who converted post a demo call by month of year (considering I'm indicating converted users as customertype = 0)

Comment: @MTay Thanks for the idea of using format(). That makes sense. Also, I've noticed that in my formula of finding the percentage, I've swapped the numerator and denominator - viz, 'two' will give me all users who've had demo calls and converted and 'one' will give me total demo calls. Just wanted to let you know so that you don't get confused with what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @Rakshit - Thanks for the info, what DBMS are you using..? I'll update my answer to suit

Comment: @MTay I'm actually doing this on Zoho Analytics. (Zoho Analytics supports full-fledged SQL based querying of your database. It understands SQL SELECT Queries written in any of the well-known database dialects including Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, IBM DB2, Sybase, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Informix and ANSI SQL). If it's possible for you to write the code in ANSI SQL that'd be great as I'm learning to code in that. Even otherwise it's no issues, I'll try figuring it out.